# Error uploading json file to a Cassandra DB through a Play application

Tags: json, scala, playframework, cassandra, playframework-2.0

I want to upload a json file to my cassandra DB by using a Play application/api.

My html view looks like this.

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {

<h1> Upload a JSON file </h1>
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "text/json") {

<input type="file" name="jsonFile">
<p>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</p>

}}
```

I defined my upload method in the controller:

```
def upload = Action(parse.json) { request =>
   val data = Json.arr(request.body)
   sc.parallelize(Seq(data)).saveToCassandra("person", "user", SomeColumns("name", "age"))
   Redirect("/index")  }
```

The error message I get is

```
Bad Request: For request 'POST /upload' [Expecting text/json or application/json body]
```

Tried with enctype "application/json" as well and there was no difference.
If I try to print the content out I get Null.

The format of my file.json is:

```
{ "name": "alice", "age": 22} 
{ "name": "bob", "age": 23}
```

Basically I can't seem to properly extract the content from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this section of the docs, about request body parsers:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Choosing-an-explicit-body-parser

Basically, `parse.json` requires that you made a request with `Content-Type` of `application/json`. From the docs:

> The json body parser will validate that the request has a Content-Type of application/json, and send back a 415 Unsupported Media Type response if the request doesn’t meet that expectation. Hence we don’t need to check again in our action code.

There is also another body parser that does not have this requirement. Again, from the docs:

> This of course means that clients have to be well behaved, sending the correct Content-Type headers with their requests. If you want to be a little more relaxed, you can instead use tolerantJson, which will ignore the Content-Type and try to parse the body as json regardless:
>
> ```
> def save = Action(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
>    Ok("Got: " + (request.body \ "name").as[String])
> }
> ```

So, you have two options here:

1. Use `parse.json` and set `Content-Type` to `application/json`
2. Use `parse.tolerantJson`

---

Besides that, you JSON file is not valid if the content is like this:

```
{ "name": "alice", "age": 22} 
{ "name": "bob", "age": 23}
```

You can check it using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and I also recommend you to read the definition at [json.org](http://json.org/). You probably want to have a array like this:

```
[
  { "name": "alice", "age": 22},
  { "name": "bob", "age": 23}
]
```

After correct the format, you can either use `parse.json` or `parse.tolerantJson`.

Comment: I have tried those two options and more. I've also gone through all the methods mentioned in the play documentation and the end result is always an error. If I switch to parse.tolerantJson I get : For request 'POST /upload' [Invalid Json: Unrecognized token 'jsonFile': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@3758e9b6; line: 1, column: 10]]   Maybe my json file is incorrectly formatted?

Comment: That fixed the Bad Requests errors. Apparently I had to change the json format a bit. Thank you. However no matter what I try I still can't get to the content of the file in question. I can get a reference to the uploaded file.json at best but not the content. Is there some particular method to access content inside of a file. Because technically the body of the POST is the file itself, not the content.

Comment: You have to edit the question to add the code of how are you trying to upload the file.

Comment: I edited my question. Removed the solved problems and updated with what my current problem is. I have there all the code that handles the whole upload procedure.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good way to use stackoverflow.com. You should probably accept this answer so other users would be able to see original answer and question. Please, revert your edit, accept this answer and open a new question.

Comment: you're right. Posted a new question about the changes.